# Using Selenium to auto login on Ubuntu with stored password

Tags: python

I'm trying to use my stored password and username to auto login with chromium

Tried googling the problem which resulted in the following.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=~/.config/chromium")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
```

i'm not getting any errors. the code just doesn't auto fill the password and username field

running ubuntu linux. python 3

Answer (score 0):

Save the form data by hand while selenium is running, close, run again and then chrome sould auto fill the fields